# jq select dynamic items from json

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have JSON like this:

```
{
  "photo_807": "Ih2RnaBTg2o.jpg",
  "photo_604": "zodCm9fQgX8.jpg",
  "photo_130": "4Dx-SUNKBw4.jpg",
  "photo_75": "7COWb8ou1qA.jpg",
  "user_id": 100,
  "owner_id": -2435432542783750,
  "access_key": "fc5275423676514042234324265cc3df7607c",
  "post_id": 380435645368865101,
  "date": 14858616848616779856424245814,
  "text": "",
  "height": 417,
  "width": 740,
  "id": 45624575446886886564368555,
  "album_id": -36
}
```

I want to get only Photo values, from output i want get this:

```
"photo_807": "Ih2RnaBTg2o.jpg"
"photo_604": "zodCm9fQgX8.jpg"
"photo_130": "4Dx-SUNKBw4.jpg"
```

Now about my problem, from next JSON file i will get photo items with new names like this:

```
  "photo_181": "Ih2RnaBTg2o.jpg",
  "photo_583": "zodCm9fQgX8.jpg",
  "photo_975": "4Dx-SUNKBw4.jpg",
  "photo_32": "7COWb8ou1qA.jpg",
```

How I can get this values from dynamic items photo_* ?

I try something like this:

```
  cat  ./json3.txt | jq  '.response.items[].attachments[].photo | select(.photo | startswith("photo"))'
```

But it doesn't work.

When I run :

```
cat  ./json3.txt | jq  '.response.items[].attachments[].photo'
```

I got this output with all items:

```
{
  "photo_807": "Ih2RnaBTg2o.jpg",
  "photo_604": "zodCm9fQgX8.jpg",
  "photo_130": "4Dx-SUNKBw4.jpg",
  "photo_75": "7COWb8ou1qA.jpg",
  "user_id": 100,
  "owner_id": -2435432542783750,
  "access_key": "fc5275423676514042234324265cc3df7607c",
  "post_id": 380435645368865101,
  "date": 14858616848616779856424245814,
  "text": "",
  "height": 417,
  "width": 740,
  "id": 45624575446886886564368555,
  "album_id": -36
}
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now I do it with grep and terrible sed combinations: cat  ./json3.txt | jq  '.response.items[].attachments[].photo' | grep "photo_" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"://'  | sed 's/",//' | sed 's/"//'   Maybe someone know how to do it only with jq ?

Comment: Provide your complete `JSON` from root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `jq` filter as below as tested on [jq-play](https://jqplay.org/s/479MnPNJDF)!

```
jq '. | to_entries[] | select(.key | startswith("photo")) | "\(.key) :\(.value)"' json
"photo_807 :Ih2RnaBTg2o.jpg"
"photo_604 :zodCm9fQgX8.jpg"
"photo_130 :4Dx-SUNKBw4.jpg"
"photo_75 :7COWb8ou1qA.jpg"
```

The idea is to use the [to_entries[]](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example23) built-in, which converts your input into a key-value pair as below. See below the output of just using `to_entries[]`

```
jq '. | to_entries[]' json
{
  "key": "photo_807",
  "value": "Ih2RnaBTg2o.jpg"
}
{
  "key": "photo_604",
  "value": "zodCm9fQgX8.jpg"
}
{
  "key": "photo_130",
  "value": "4Dx-SUNKBw4.jpg"
}
{
  "key": "photo_75",
  "value": "7COWb8ou1qA.jpg"
}
{
  "key": "user_id",
  "value": 100
}
{
  "key": "owner_id",
  "value": -2435432542783750
}
{
  "key": "access_key",
  "value": "fc5275423676514042234324265cc3df7607c"
}
{
  "key": "post_id",
  "value": 380435645368865100
}
{
  "key": "date",
  "value": 14858616848616779000000000000
}
{
  "key": "text",
  "value": ""
}
{
  "key": "height",
  "value": 417
}
{
  "key": "width",
  "value": 740
}
{
  "key": "id",
  "value": 45624575446886885000000000
}
{
  "key": "album_id",
  "value": -36
}
```

On this output, we are filtering on the `.key` value which starts with your string, `photo` in your case, using the built-in [startswith()](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example49), and printing the both the `.key` and `.value` pair for the matching objects.

Comment: Thank you Inian! Very intresting! But when I run command - jq '.response.items[].attachments[].photo | to_entries[] | select(.key | startswith("photo")) | "\(.key) :\(.value)"' ./json3.txt  I got error startswith is not defined. What I do wrong?

Comment: I thought the input provided is your complete json, provide the complete one, from `.response.items[].attachments[]` @Darkwind

Comment: @Darkwind - If your jq does not have startswith, it is very ancient. Please try to upgrade it to at least jq 1.4

Comment: Thank you @peak! I upgrade jq to 1.5 version and now it works!